# Where is the xml file generated saved after running xmlrunner?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have my unittest suite and this piece of code. Where is the xml file saved?

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main(verbosity=2, testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(filename='test-reports.xml'))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For this to work, xml should be in the same directory of this python file (your current working directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was running the tests with PyCharm's predefined running settings for unittest, however this requires the following command to run and generate the files:

```
python -m <name-of-the-test>
```